# Searching in results SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables:

**Table 1**

```
Name | Surname
```

**Table 2**

```
Introduce | Type
```

Introduce from Table 2 contains either Name or Surname or both from Table1. I'm listing all records from Table1 that are not present in Introduce and that's working just fine.

What I'm trying to do is limit those results using Type from Table2.

I'm trying such code:

```
select t1.Name, t1.Surname
from Table1 t1
where not exists (select 1 Introduce
                  from Table2 t2
                  where (t2.Introduce like ('%' + t1.Name+ '%') 
                         or t2.Introduce LIKE ('%' + t1.Surname + '%'))
                 )
  and exists (select Type
              from Table2
              where Type in (90, 120))
```

But there's no difference if I'm using `and exists...` or not, same results.

Comment: `Introduce from Table 2 contains either Name or Surname or both from Table1.`Sounds like bad design. Maybe if you give more details of these tables that could clear things up a little what you are looking for

Comment: And post some sample data and expected outcome

Answer (score 0):

Change you WHERE clause to

```
where not exists 
    (   SELECT 1 Introduce
        from Table2 t2
        where (t2.Introduce like ('%' + t1.Name+ '%') or t2.Introduce LIKE ('%' + t1.Surname + '%'))
        and T2.Type in (90, 120)
    )
```

and your design needs changing. It shouldn't be denormalised

Comment: I already tried that, no changes, same results as before. What do you mean by "denormalised"?

Comment: For example, Table 1 should have an `Id` column defined as `INT IDENTITY` and then Table2 should reference this `Id` column as a `Foreign Key` in the `Introduce` Column. you wouldn't then need the crazy wildcard induced where clause

Comment: I'm afraid that's impossible as Table1 and Table2 got different data, most of Introduce rows don't contain anything from Table1.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.Name, t1.Surname
from Table1 t1
where not exists 
    (   SELECT 1 Introduce
        from Table2 t2
        where (t2.Introduce like ('%' + t1.Name+ '%') or t2.Introduce LIKE ('%' + t1.Surname + '%'))
        and T2.Type in (90, 120)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select name, surname from table1 [t1]
left join (select * from table2 where type in (90, 120)) [t2]
on CHARINDEX([t1].name, [t2].Introduce) > 0 or CHARINDEX([t1].surname, [t2].Introduce) > 0
where [t2].introduce is null
```

Comment: That's working exacly as my query but still Type is not used here. When I'm typing it in where clause there's no output data instead.

Comment: @n0rek Check updated answer. Also, share your data and desired output. I can't help you anymore. On my table it works perfectly.